# What does this all mean for the enemy?

Tags: javascript, support

This enemy JS file in a space shooting game was part of tutorial but there was no explanation to what is does and more importantly **Why**.

Can you please help me explain what the following mean in the code?

- "dt"
- "Math.abs"

```js
moveTowardPoint(dt) {
        let inc = dt * this.speed;
        this.incrementPosition(inc * this.targetWayPoint.dir_x, inc * this.targetWayPoint.dir_y);

        if(Math.abs(this.position.x - this.targetWayPoint.point.x) < Math.abs(inc) &&
        Math.abs(this.position.y - this.targetWayPoint.point.y) < Math.abs(inc)) {
            this.updatePosition( this.targetWayPoint.point.x,  this.targetWayPoint.point.y);
        }

        if(this.position.equalToPoint(this.targetWayPoint.point.x, this.targetWayPoint.point.y) == true) {
            if (this.targetWayPointNumber == this.lastWayPointIndex) {
                this.killMe();
                console.log('reached end');
            } else {
                this.setNextWayPoint();
            }
        }
    }
```

Small points are more than enough. I have an overall understand that the file needs to do.

Thank you!

Comment: You might need a better tutorial, then. Can you be more specific about what parts of that file you don't understand? It is hard to tell what level of explanation you require. You can not expect anyone to explain every single one of these 161 lines of code to you. Also, *you* might have "an overall understand that the file needs to do" but your readers might not, because they have no idea which one of the countless javascript tutorials available you are talking about.

Comment: OK, will do. Thank you for the helpful advice Philipp.

btw, do you mind @Philipp suggesting a good website for beginners code reviews if you know one?

Comment: Regarding code review for code **you** wrote: https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Please read [this article](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) before you post.

Comment: Add extra clarification to the Q above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt` is very likely a shorthand for "delta time", the time in seconds which expired since the last time this method was called. It is not easy to ensure that a function in JavaScript gets called in *exact* time intervals. It is usually easier to just schedule it to be executed when opportune (like on `requestAnimationFrame`) and take the time since the last update into account.

`*` is the symbol for multiplication in JavaScript. `let inc = dt * this.speed;` means "the variable inc is the speed of this object, multiplied with delta time". Speed multiplied by time is distance. So it appears to be the distance by which something is supposed to move during this update.

The purpose of `Math.abs` can be found in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) (Which I, by the way, just accessed by entering "Math.abs JavaScript" into my browsers search bar). It removes the minus-sign from numerical values. `Math.abs(-3)` is 3. `Math.abs(3)` is also 3. In this case it is used to measure the difference between two values. The author does not care which number is bigger and which one is smaller, they just want to know how far the two points are apart from each other. So they subtract the two values from each other and run the result through `Math.abs`. That way they get the same value for `6 - 3` as they get for `3 - 6`.

Comment: Thank @philipp.That was very helpful.